# Handling PHP POST variable from other php file and managing $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]

Tags: php, post

I stucked at a problem I can't figure out why isn't is working.

I am handling POST variable from another php file:

```
$temp_variable = $_POST['activity'];
```

After my code process $temp_variable, I try to make a button (still in the same php file where I handled $_POST['activity'])

```
echo '<form action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'" method="post">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="OK" name="process_more"/>';
echo '</form>';
```

Then I try to catch OK button press, to start another activity:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

$query = "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id = 5";    
mysqli_query($conn,$query)
}
```

My problem is that the "Delete FROM" part of the code executes immediately, before the user press the "OK" button.

What can be the problem ?

Comment: All of your PHP is processed server-side. There is no way, without separating things, that you can stop a PHP script for input via the browser.

Comment: `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"` will return true because the post from the other PHP file. I suggest to check for post variable specific to the form. Example `!empty($_POST['process_more'])`

Comment: Jay Blanchard, rz3993: thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check something more specific to your form.

```
if(isset($_POST['process_more'])){
    if ($_POST['process_more'] == 'OK') {

    // execute the delete
    }
}
```

`$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` could equal `'POST'` from a different form submission..

Comment: This will cause undefined index notice because $_POST['process_more'] doesn't exist yet when the first post occur, don't you think?

Comment: No.  The 'test' will return false, and the code inside will not execute.

Comment: I mean in the error log, notice won't halt the code by default.

Comment: OK, check that it exists first then... ...updated code now

Comment: Chris Maggs, frz3993: thank you for the answer and the help!